# Adding a few images to a new post from front-end form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

Have a front-end form to create a post, Am only able to add text data to the new post (title, content, text-typed custom fields). When I want to create a new post, I want to be able to assign images to them too. If it's possible I want it to be different number of images for each post. (Ex. User be able to assign between 1 to 5 images for a new post).

It's a WordPress site and I use Avada theme. The custom post type is the Avada's default Portfolio post. But any generalised answer with some explanation would be much appreciated.

Here's my php code in fuctions.php in my child-theme:

```
    if(isset($_POST['title'])){

    $custom_field_address1 = $_POST['address1'];

    $my_post = array(

    'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
        
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name',
    'meta_input' => array(
        'address1' => $custom_field_address1,
        )
    );
    
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'address1', $custom_field_address1, false );
    echo 'New Post Saved !';
    
    die;
   }
```

My fron-end form (I want to be able to add a few images from here when I want to add a new post):

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Post Title:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
</div>
    
    
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Post Description :</label>
      <textarea class="form-control"  name="description"></textarea>
</div>
      
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="address1">Address :</label>
      <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1">
</div>

<BR>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure of adding an image to the Post:

1. get the existing post content with `get_post_field`
2. upload the image with `wp_insert_attachment` which gives you the image
   ID
3. grab the image size and alt from the post content somehow
4. let WP generate the markup for the image with `wp_get_attachment_image`
5. replace the old image placeholder with the new image html
6. when all of the image placeholders have been replaced with img tags, save the modified post content to DB with `wp_update_post`

Optionally set any of the images as the post thumbnail / featured image with `set_post_thumbnail`.

```
global $user_ID;

$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Title Of Post',
    'post_content' => 'Contents',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(1),
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
//$post_id = 1234; //example Post ID
$images = array('filename1.png', 'filename2.png', ... 'filename10.png'); //example images

// Get post content
$post_content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id );

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

foreach($images as $name) {
  $attachment = array(
    'guid'=> $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $name ), 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/png',
    'post_title' => 'my description',
    'post_content' => 'my description',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
  );

  /**
    * STEP 1
    * add images as attachments to WordPress
    */
  $image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $name, $post_id);
  // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
  // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
  $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image_id, $name );
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image_id, $attach_data );

  /**
    * STEP 2
    * Grab image data from $post_content
    */
  // strpos() + substr() maybe?
  $width = 123;
  $height = 123;
  $alt = 'Hello';

  /**
    * STEP 3
    * get html markup for image
    */  
  // Let WP generate the html markup for the image, adjust size as needed (thumbnail,medium,large,full,array(width,height))
  $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, array( $width, $height ), false, array( 'alt' => $alt ) );

  /**
    * STEP 4
    * Replace placeholders in content with img markup
    */
  preg_replace( $pattern, $image_html, $post_content ) // I don't understand regex well enough to give an example, so you need to figure it out yourself

  /**
    * OPTIONAL
    * set image as featured
    */
  if ( $name === 'example' ) {
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image_id );
  }

}

/**
  * STEP 5
  * Update post content
  */
$post_with_imported_images = array(
  'ID'           => $post_id,
  'post_content' => $post_content,
);
wp_update_post( $post_with_imported_images );
```

Comment: With a quick look, I noticed you meant it to add image to existing posts. I want it to add a image when I create a post. I'll try to use your beautiful codes to implement what I want. Or if you can you may edit it for that purpose and I'll be more thankful.

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to just put other post stuff that you want.